# How to return a different object based on Optional's null check on another different object in java?

Tags: java, java-8, nullpointerexception, option-type

How to convert this to modern Java syntax using Optionals?

```
public String computeName(Person person) {
    if(person != null) return person.getName();
    return null;
}
```

I tried this, but of course this is wrong because orElse will return an instance of Person object, not the String name. For this to work, I would need to chain another optional I think.

```
public String getName(Person person) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(person).orElse(person.getName());
}
```

I want to reduce the code and make this work using modern java syntax using Optionals. Or any other standard library is also fine like ApaceUtils or Google-Guava etc.

Essentially, I want to return person's name if the person object itself is not null. I am fine if my method returns null instead of a string in some cases as well, since the caller always checks using Apache Commons StringUtils.isNotBlank(which also check for null by the way).

Comment: `return person == null ? null : person.getName();` is concise since the return type is **not** an Optional<String>.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking of doing as well. But just wanted to see if there was a better or rather more concise approach using Optionals or any third party library. I have a lot of places where I need to do this and I feel like `x == null ? y : z;` looks quite bad if I have too many such lines in single class or single method.Thanks

Comment: excuse me but would't person.getName() throw NullPointerException and not return null?

Comment: What is the point of having an `if` statement, when the statement for a true condition is **exactly the same** `return` statement as the statement following the `if` statement?

Comment: *"How to convert this to modern Java syntax using Optionals?"* --- You do it by not using `Optional`, but by remove irrelevant code: `public String getName(Person person) { return person.getName(); }`

Comment: why would you need a function "getName" that accepts nullable person in the first place? and why do you need this external getter that only defers to the getter inside of Person?

Comment: @Yamahari You are *assuming* that the shown method is in the `Person` class. That is not at all a given. Probable, but not given.

Comment: @Yamahari Nice catch, made a mistake while trying to frame the question. Updated the code now.

Comment: I feel like people are getting sidetracked by thinking about method name and if it should be a getter on a simple Pojo. I changed the name to computeName and just imagine that this is not an instance method but some method in util class which `can take a null object` and returns a property on that object.

Comment: this is NOT a valid case nor "modern" usage of Optional. Simple null check is perfect. Stop posting wrong usage of API, someone will have to scrub after you. I swear, everyday there is another Optional question with different getter ...

Comment: True I guess, but that's how the code was written and I don't want to touch the caller code and thereby invoking the QA test process for the feature all over again. Hence the question since we are trying to use as much modern syntax where needed. Thanks what you said is indeed the right way to use Optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```java
> public static String computeName(Person person) {
>     if(person != null) return person.getName();
>     return null;
> }
> ```

There are 2 ways to convert the above code to "modern Java syntax using `Optional`":

1. Incomplete conversion, keeping the signature unchanged:

   ```java
   public static String computeName(Person person) {
       return Optional.ofNullable(person).map(Person::getName).orElse(null);
   }
   ```
2. Full conversion:

   ```java
   public static Optional<String> computeName(Person person) {
       return Optional.ofNullable(person).map(Person::getName);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I was looking for. I think I missed the step of having a `.map` after `ofNullable`.

Comment: Two cents - the first version is much useful when you instead do `.orElse("defaultValue")`.

Comment: @Naman If you did that, it would *not* be working the same as before the conversion, so that is not a functionally *useful* suggestion.

Comment: Ofcourse, I meant that's where the other "full conversion" option is preferrable.

Comment: @Naman No, the preferable full conversion is to use `Optional` the way it is intended, i.e. to tell the caller that it's possible a name is not available and that the caller needs to handle that. The purpose of `Optional` is not what option #1 shows, i.e. doing null checks without using `if` statements, it is to document that return value may not be available, and *force* the caller to handle that, thereby helping to prevent `NullPointerException` when caller forgot to do a null check, which is otherwise a bomb in the code waiting to go off when least expected.